# How to work around OpenSSL's PRNG limitation in Python forked processes?

Tags: python, ssl

The documentation for the "ssl" module in the Python 2.7.9 standard library says:

> If using this module as part of a multi-processed application (using, for example the multiprocessing or concurrent.futures modules), be aware that OpenSSL’s internal random number generator does not properly handle forked processes. Applications must change the PRNG state of the parent process if they use any SSL feature with os.fork(). Any successful call of RAND_add(), RAND_bytes() or RAND_pseudo_bytes() is sufficient.

What does it really mean in concrete terms? Should I call one of those three functions in the master process after each fork?

Also, does this apply to multiple threads?

In case it's relevant, I have a Django application running on the Gunicorn server. The master process doesn't do anything with SSL, but the workers do.

Comment: Doesn't gunicorn have a prefork/forkserver model, which would make this irrelevant in the first place? Or are you manually calling `os.fork` yourself somewhere or something?

Comment: That's a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it really mean in concrete terms?

I believe the details are in [#18747](http://bugs.python.org/issue18747).

The main risk is that each child gets a copy of the PRNG state. If you fork two children without touching the PRNG in between, they may get identical PRNG state, presumably allowing prediction attacks. NIST's [CVE 2013-1900](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1900) describes the equivalent attack vector against Postgres as "generates insufficiently random numbers, which might allow remote authenticated users to have an unspecified impact". Not all that specific…

> The master process doesn't do anything with SSL, but the workers do.

Well, the problem is the possibility of not doing anything with SSL between two forks, so never doing anything with SSL pretty much guarantees that…

Except that if you're absolutely sure you never even *initialize* SSL, then the children will initialize (and seed) SSL for themselves the first time they need it. I'm not sure of a good way to convince yourself that this is happening, but it might be worth trying. (Maybe monkeypatch SSL at startup, then unpatch it after fork, so if you do indirectly touch it everything will die?)

> Should I call one of those three functions in the master process after each fork?

I would err on the side of caution. Is this going to be difficult to do, or an efficiency concern?

If it's a matter of being difficult, you could just always seed the RNG at the start of each child instead.<sup>*</sup> For a traditional prefork server, which starts a worker for each connection, that could be disastrously inefficient, but I'm pretty sure [gunicorn doesn't work that way](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html). It creates a pool of workers (which I think defaults to 2*NCPU+1) at startup, maybe it recycles them occasionally, but new clients either wait for a free worker (in the sync model) or goes into a worker's gevent/asyncio/thread/etc. pool (in the various async models). So the cost of a child's startup time should be irrelevant. (If I'm wrong, please ignore this guess—or, better, correct my ignorance…)

> Also, does this apply to multiple threads?

No, threads will (mutably) share the same RNG state, not get copies of it, so you're safe there. (And of course that goes for gunicorn/gevent microthreads, too.)

---

<sub>* I originally suggested or uninitialize OpenSSL and reinitialize it, bit turns out that if you do that, at least if there are threads in either master or server, everything goes to hell. So don't do that, just seed.</sub>

Comment: OK. So the issue that they refer to is only to do with poor randomness, nothing else like Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) related issues, right?

Comment: @Gustavo: Right, it's just poor randomness. And the fact that someone trying to work around it (at least in a program with all three of forks, threads, and signals) could end up screwing things up badly, so they wanted to give specific advice on exactly how to do so.

Comment: @abarnert If we consider following python bug/feature https://bugs.python.org/issue33023 then it looks like it is impossible to have scenarios where in SSLSocket object [based on OpenSSL] can be passed to child process. And then issue reported by OP becomes a non issue. Please correct me if this is not the case.